# iOS ignores container width for Swiper gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, ipad

I am making a simplified swiper gallery, where I only need it to hide the default browser scroller and swipe through the images. I am using jQuery and TouchSwipe plugin for the swipe logic. So far I have written this code: https://jsfiddle.net/drbj6zk8/5/. I have added containers (calculated by getting (div.swipe -  div.swipe-wrapper) and the swiper should not go outside these borders.

$(function() {

```
var currentTranslation = 0;
var lastDistance = 0;
var translationDelta = 0;
var containerLengthArr = $('div.swipe-slide');
var containerLength = 0;
var containerBorder = 0;

$("#test5").swipe({
    swipeStatus: swipe2,
    allowPageScroll: "horizontal"
});
/*TODO*/

$.each(containerLengthArr, function(e) {
    containerLength += ($(this).width() + 10);
})
$('.swipe-wrapper').width(containerLength + 5);
containerBorder = $('.swipe').width() - $('.swipe-wrapper').width();
console.log(containerBorder);

//Swipe handlers

function swipe2(event, phase, direction, distance) {
    var check = $(this).children('.swipe-slide');
    if (phase == "end") {
        translationDelta = 0;
    } else {
        translationDelta = lastDistance - distance;
    }
    /*Check direction*/
    if (direction == "right") {
        currentTranslation -= translationDelta;
    } else if (direction == "left") {
        currentTranslation += translationDelta;
    }
    var distance2 = 0;
    /*Limit slider to wrapper lenghth*/
    if (currentTranslation > 0) {
        distance2 = "translateX(" + 0 + "px)";
        currentTranslation = 0;
    }
    else if (currentTranslation < containerBorder) {
        distance2 = "translateX(" + containerBorder + "px)";
        currentTranslation = containerBorder;
    }
    else {
        distance2 = "translateX(" + currentTranslation + "px)";
    }

    check.css('transform', distance2);
    lastDistance = distance;

    console.log(currentTranslation);
}
```

});

Of course, everything works fine on desktop browsers and Android devices, but I bumped into an issue with iOS devices. There is absolutely no consistency with the behavior across the different devices (iphone 5, iphone 6, iPad). On all of them I am getting different and more importantly broken behaviors (either the slider does not look the same and more importantly, the swiper goes beyond the set borders).

Does anybody know what I am missing or if there is some specific requirements for this to work on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

I did some more digging and it turned out that it is a bug with the jquery plugin. It doesn't properly "read" the distance on iOS. The workaround provided was to either downgrade to version 1.6.9 or to edit the plugin.

Reference: https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin/issues/260